# USB-Port stopped working,no keyboard mouse But can rdp and remotely access

Tags: networking, usb, windows-7-x64

All of sudden i lost connectivity on all usb port. 
it started last week when front usb where i use to charge my phone stopped and i kind of ignored. and now 3 days ago mouse n keyboard stopped.
I am a software person with less knowledge in this area.
Operation team tried hard to fix but could not. and now asking me to use a complete new system and reinstall everything.dont want to give up this easily.
In past stackoverflow genius helped me to fix some hardware issues.
I can work n RDP to my box using laptop . and want to give last try .
Please suggest .
I have uninstalled n reinstalled n update drivers but not detecting .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your USB physical hardware may have failed. One way to test it would be to reboot into your hardware diagnostics to see its a reported failure.

Alternatively if you are familiar with Ubuntu, create and boot into a live ubuntu dvd/USB key.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

It will not break anything on your existing computer at all, simply reboot and your back in your old O/S.

Comment: thanks a lot Stuart. i tried -http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dead-usb-port-heres-how-to-diagnose-and-fix-it/  and "Disable Selective Suspend Feature" of article made my front usb port working. back ports still dead and cant try ubuntu trial as CD drive disabled for all at desktop.any other suggestion?